# TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'groups')

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

After training a CNN model in TensorFlow-Keras I got this error mentioned in the title while opening the model file with the following function:

```
from tensorflow.keras import load_model
# I also tried:
# from tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.models import load_model

model = load_model('weights-improvement-70-0.57.hdf5', compile = False)
```

`weights-improvement-70-0.57.hdf5` is my model file. Following is the detailed form of the error which I am quoting from the terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing_with_landmark.py", line 59, in <module>
    PREDICTOR = load_model('weights-improvement-70-0.57.hdf5', compile = True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/save.py", line 143, in load_model
    return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py", line 162, in load_model_from_hdf5
    custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/saving/model_config.py", line 55, in model_from_config
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/serialization.py", line 105, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 191, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/sequential.py", line 368, in from_config
    custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/serialization.py", line 105, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 193, in deserialize_keras_object
    return cls.from_config(cls_config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 601, in from_config
    return cls(**config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 498, in __init__
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 122, in __init__
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/base.py", line 457, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 300, in __init__
    generic_utils.validate_kwargs(kwargs, allowed_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 599, in validate_kwargs
    raise TypeError(error_message, kwarg)
TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'groups')
```

Why this is happening?

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think the problem is because you are tying to load model weights as a model. you should fist create the model or load from the saved model and then use: `load_weights(<model_weight_path>)`

Comment: @Ashwin Geet D'Sa thanks! Actually it was the case. `tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,save_weights_only=True,verbose=1)` by default saves the weights only but I assumed the opposite.

Comment: Please let me know if it can go as an answer.

Comment: @Ashwin Geet D'Sa yes, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you are tying to load model weights as a model.

To load a model you should fist create the model or load from the saved model (a json file or model checkpoint) and then use: `load_weights(<model_weight_path>)`